# Pass parameters to sub nodes resolvers functions

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo, apollo-server

I have this graphql query, its looking for all services associated with a project( given its id ) and for each services, it returns the list of users who have access to.

```
query Project ($id: ID!) {
  services {
    mailService {
      users
    }
  }
}
```

I want to know what's the best solution to pass the `id` parameter and use it inside the `users` resolver function.

I am thinking about these solutions :

- Add $id parameter for both mailService and users nodes in query.
- In the graphql middleware in server, add parameters object to the context field ( from the request.body)
- Add a field in context object in Project resolver : context.projectId = $id and use it in sub fields resolvers.

Thanks for help

Comment: Why does your `users` resolver need to know about the project ID? I feel like that would be confusing from the API consumer point of view.

Comment: The main reason is because i need to call 2 different Rest APIs to get Project  basic infos and to get the list of users who have accees to a service. The second API take 2 params: projectId and service identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with native resolve form the object types.

In the resolve of the sub node, you can access the entire parent data.
For example:

```
export const User: GraphQLObjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    description: 'User type',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
            description: 'The user id.',
        },
        name: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
            description: 'The user name.',
        },
        friends: {
            type: new GraphQLList(User),
            description: 'User friends',
            resolve: (source: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) => {
                console.log('friends source: ', source)
                return [
                    {id: 1, name: "friend1"},
                    {id: 2, name: "friend2"},
                ]
            }
        }
    }),
})

const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    description: 'Root Query',
    fields: () => ({
        user: {
            type: User,
            description: User.description,
            args: {
                id: {
                    type: GraphQLInt,
                    description: 'the user id',
                }
            },
            resolve: (source: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) => {
                console.log('user args: ', args)
                return { id: 2, name: "user2" }
            }
        }
    })
})
```

In the `friends` resolve the `source` param has the entire returned values from the parent `user` resolve. So in here I could fetch all the friends based on the user ID I get from `source`.